# Unable to find files in Recycle.bin but they show up in Transport Tree and taking space on hard drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, recycle-bin

We have a Windows Server 2008 (standard, not R2) where we are rapidly losing disk space on the C drive and don't know what is eating it up.  We cleared up the C drive and created over 6GB of space, and in 4 days it was gone.  Here is some background info:

- Total size of the C drive is 65 GB and we have only 3.42 GB left as of now.
- Folder `C:\Windows\Winsxs` is at 15.6GB.

I have run diskclean up multiple times.  Finally I copied the C drive to a external hard drive and ran TreeSize Professional on it. It shows two things taking up all the space...one is the C drive and then interestingly Recycle bin showing almost the exact amount of space as the C drive (see pictures).  The odd thing is this is almost the space missing in the C drive.  (C drive total space is 65GB and we are using 32GB that can be accounted for).  I have checked recycle bin and Recycle folder but didn't find anything.  I have gone and ahead and cleared it using `rd /s /q C:\$Recycle.bin`.  My question is how can I drill down on this `$Recycle.Bin` that is showing up on TreeeSize but I cannot see anything on the actual C drive.  The full path for the folder under Recycle bin is 
`C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-3480402611-2939412034-2664725923-500\$RQ30AMQ\MailboxDatabase.edb` with the size of 29,623.8MB.

Comment: If you have an image that illustrates relevant information that you can't easily express in text, post it *somewhere*, and [edit] your question to include the URL; somebody might insert the image into the question for you. Also, can you clarify what you mean by "recycle bin ***and*** Recycle folder"?

Answer (score 0):

The Recycling Bin is a special folder, and Windows (especially Explorer) is doing it's best to hide the contents of others' Recycling Bins from you.

You'll need to use a tool like TreeSize (as you did) or an alternate Explorer (like [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/), etc.) to access them directly.

There are also tools specific to the task as well, like [rifiuti2](http://code.google.com/p/rifiuti2/).